# How can I pass the zip to the button function?

Tags: javascript

I did wrap this in a form with a submit button, but realized that this attempted to go to a new page without performing the logic. How can I pass the zip code to the onclick button event? If this is completely wrong, can you provide guidance onto how to perform this correctly.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" name="zip" required />

<button id="checker">Go!</button>

<script>
  var b = document.getElementById("checker");

  b.addEventListener("click", function checkZipCode(zip) {

        var zipCodes = [26505, 26501, 26507, 26506];

        for (i = 0; i <= zipCodes.length - 1; i++) {
          if (zip == zipCodes[i]) {
            alert("YES");
            break;
          }
        }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was not added into the code                                                  <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" pattern ="[0-9]{5}" name="zip" required />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value of your input and you can do this with `document.querySelector('[name="zip"]').value`

```js
var b = document.getElementById("checker");

b.addEventListener("click", function checkZipCode(zip) {
  var zip = document.querySelector('[name="zip"]').value;
  var zipCodes = [26505, 26501, 26507, 26506];
  for (i = 0; i <= zipCodes.length - 1; i++) {
    if (zip == zipCodes[i]) {
      alert("YES");
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" name="zip" required />


<button id="checker">Go!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `getElementById('ELEMENT_NAME_HERE').value` like so:

Go!

```
  <script>
    var b = document.getElementById("checker");

    b.addEventListener("click", function checkZipCode(zip){

        console.log('Clicked');
        var enteredZip = document.getElementById("zip").value; 
        console.log(enteredZip);
        var zipCodes=[26505, 26501, 26507, 26506];

        for(i=0; i<=zipCodes.length-1; i++){
            if(zip == zipCodes[i]){
                alert("YES");
                break;
            }}}); 
</script>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ptyUAItwyaSmZXsD81xK?p=preview

You can't pass it in.

Comment: Except the input has no ID

Comment: Except adding id is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Why is adding an ID the "cleanest way"? There's no need to add anything to the DOM.

Comment: There is no need to use dirty attribute values either.

Comment: Dirty attribute values? What are those?

Comment: The dirty html attribute value look up in your code.

Comment: Can you explain what about that is "dirty"? I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

basically if this myfunction() will return a false then the form would not be submitted;
Also this would only be performed at the time of submittion of the form

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input id='input-id' type="submit">
</form>
```

> 

```
<script>
myfunction(){

if(/*some condition*/)
{
return false; 
}
  </script>
```

Also few things to consider since you seem new and people here are giving you very correct but specific solutions.

if you add a button to inside  tag, that would submit the form on clicking it.
That is why many use a div which looks like a button by css. Mainly a clean solution to override the Button submit and also you can simply submit the form by Javascript.

Comment: @j08691 I think you also suggest the answer by VSO, but his real problem is something else. Did not wanted to just write the whole answer for him.